# Многостраничность во Vue

Tags: vue.js

Не могу понять, если ли во Vue возможность делать многостраничное приложение без VueRouter? Или это вообще не нужно?

Answer (score 3):

Возможно. написать свой роутер на чистом js используя History

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History

Вот статья хорошая с примером

https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/439824/

> Или это вообще не нужно?

Зависит от задач,  VueRouter - однозначно самое простое и надежное решение вместе с Vue

Если приложение совсем маленькое то можно и просто v-if и тд обойтись.